# Поддержка  jQuery в Aptana 3

Tags: jquery, aptana, ide

Использую [Aptana Studio 3 Beta](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3)  , устраивает меня всем (поддержка PHP из коробки, есть тёмные цветовые схемы). Но, к сожалению, нет менеджера плагинов, как во 2-й версии, и соответственно, невозможно привычным методом поставить поддержку jQuery. Как можно её включить, и возможно ли это в принципе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Studio 3 большая часть такого рода функциональности все еще дорабатываются, на то она и beta.

Тем не менее, уже есть JQuery, если вы не устанавливали, можно установить с помощью Aptana Commands Menu (Commands->Bundle Development->Install Bundle, а затем выберите JQuery из списка).

По словам гугла надо добавить (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js) в проект. Это, кажется, ключ.